# creating word cloud with d3.js

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js, word-cloud

I am trying to create word cloud using `d3.js` and `d3.layout.cloud.js`.

For this I am using `.csv` file which contains rows `word,size`. But unable to create the file.
Unable to understand that where I'am going wrong with this.

Following is my code:

[Word Cloud creation using `d3.js` in `.csv`](http://plnkr.co/edit/zHIddcwFhHELVKJkghbM?p=preview)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`d3.csv` is an asynchronous call. That means that it doesn't return anything, you have to process the data in the callback. I've done that (and fixed a few other things) [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/7ADBWmu3CJm1NTFm0sR2?p=preview). I've also limited the font sizes to be between 8 and 24 as the values in your data are rather large.

Comment: Ok. But Its not displaying every data. As we are just taking the word from the csv file how are we gonna get to know that which word frequency is higher

Comment: The area you've set is quite small, so some of the words were falling off the screen. I've update the example to be larger.

Comment: I have tried with this with various ranges of data but I only seem to get either a very small or medium font size,as in just 2 levels of scaling.